# Why are these JSTL c:tests not stopping the content from being rendered?

Tags: java, jsf-2, jstl

I just wanted to demonstrate why we should not be using JSTL tags to a colleague but I got lost not sure why is every thing getting rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">    
     <h:outputLabel>#{dummyBean.pageBuild}</h:outputLabel>
     <h:outputLabel>#{dummyBean.pageRerendered}</h:outputLabel>     
     <h:outputLabel>#{dummyBean.pageBuild and !dummyBean.pageRerendered}</h:outputLabel>
     <h:outputLabel>#{dummyBean.pageBuild and dummyBean.pageRerendered}</h:outputLabel>
        <c:if test="#{dummyBean.pageBuild and !dummyBean.pageRerendered}">
             <h:outputLabel value="Section 1"></h:outputLabel>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{dummyBean.pageBuild and dummyBean.pageRerendered}">
            <h:outputLabel value="Section 2"></h:outputLabel>
        </c:if>

</ui:composition>
```

Results are

```
true
false
true
false 
Section 1 
Section 2
```

I would have thought they would be

```
true
false
true
false 
Section 1
```

Comment: test="false" doesn't seem like an expression. shouldn't it be more like test=${1==0}? My jstl fu is very weak, its been quite sometime, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Why do you think you shouldn't be using JSTL?

Comment: @erickson word of god i.e. balusc :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense . By the way not saying should never be using it but checking `rendered =...` is better .

Comment: @erickson, trying to render complex visual models becomes quite tricky with jstl. (like rendering tables and nested forms). Any thing thing done with jstl can be done more easily with custom tags. It is easy to teach custom tags to new java programmers.

Comment: In the context of JSF, I agree it can be tricky to use JSTL correctly. But I disagree that custom tags are easier to use than JSTL; that sounds like NIH syndrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<c:if test="true">
     <h:outputLabel value="Section 1.1"></h:outputLabel>
</c:if>

<c:if test="false">
    <h:outputLabel value="Section 2.2"></h:outputLabel>
</c:if>
```

The `test="true"` and `test="false"` will always evaluate as boolean `true`, simply because it are valid and non-null `String` values.

You likely meant to use `test="#{true}"` and `test="#{false}"` instead.

```html
<c:if test="#{true}">
     <h:outputLabel value="Section 1.1" />
</c:if>

<c:if test="#{false}">
    <h:outputLabel value="Section 2.2" />
</c:if>
```

Another problem is that the XML namespace for JSTL tags is wrong, you're using the one of Facelets 1.x while you're using JSF 2.x. It should be

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

As to using JSTL in JSF, check this answer: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: Have already checked and just mentioned in my comments before you anwered :) . For my question though what about ` <c:if test="#{dummyBean.pageBuild and !dummyBean.pageRerendered}">
             <h:outputLabel value="Section 1"></h:outputLabel>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{dummyBean.pageBuild and dummyBean.pageRerendered}">
            <h:outputLabel value="Section 2"></h:outputLabel>
        </c:if>'

Comment: I removed `section1.1 and section2.2` from the question but what about `section1 and section2 ` the outputs above showing true or false based of what I expect.

Comment: using `<c:if test="#{false}">` is also not stopping `<h:outputLabel value="Section 2.2" />` from being displayed.

Comment: The XML namespace of core taglib is wrong, so they would not be parsed at all and interpreted as plain HTML.

Comment: I have the right namespace and still if I do <c:if test="false"> it won't enter the condition.